# Toggle the_excerpt and the_content on a masonry styled gallery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to toggle between my posts' the_excerpt and the_content on a masonry styled gallery, but it affects every single post instead of just the one that was clicked.

```
<div class="card-columns">
   <?php
$postCases = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'cases',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

    while ($postCases->have_posts()) {
    $postCases->the_post(); 
?>

   <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h4 class="card-title section-subtitle text-center"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
         <p class="card-text excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
         <p class="text-center read more"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></p>
         <p class="case-content"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".read").click(function() {
    $('.case-content').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Whenever .read is clicked, it's supposed to toggle the_content of that specific post. Instead, it toggles all the other contents as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hide the content.

```
<style>
.case-content{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

you can use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) fuction. When click on read more button find the very next sibling of the selected element with a class 'case-content' and apply the Toggle.

like.

```
 $(".read").on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.case-content').slideToggle('slow');
  });
```

Comment: thank you!! the next function was exactly what i needed. it works perfectly now!